# Strolling Image - VB.net to get the latest colour

Tags: vb.net

Need some guidance, the image below is scrolling on a website, from right to left, the colors will change between red or green, which are 255 values of each. Im not sure how i would do about seeing what the latest colour is as it scrolls, the example below shows that the red is the latest, but a few seconds ago the green was. Is there a way to say what the latest colour was.

I'm taking a BMP image off a window every 2 seconds, just after a textbox that says red or green. I cant see any example code of something similar on here, nor google.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Pete

[image]

Comment: This is a bit of guess here, since you're already snapshooting the image at points in time, it's just a case of finding the target pixel(s) and inspecting it's color.  How you find that target pixel is probably the hard part, but thinking something like non-white pixels?

Answer (score 0):

You can search the bitmap for the target colors and add them into a `Dictionary(Of Color, Point)`, add or update the value of each color in the dictionary (the point) whenever you find the key color at a greater `X` position. Use the [`LockBits`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=net-5.0) approach to traverse the bitmap's bytes for faster and better performance.

When you have the dictionary filled with the required data, sort the values by their `X` properties in descending order and return the key (the color) of the first.

```vb
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

' TODO: Find a better name...
Private Function GetLastColor(bmp As Bitmap, ParamArray colors() As Color) As Color
    If bmp Is Nothing Then Return Color.Empty

    ' To work with 24-bit and 32-bit images...
    Dim bpp = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(bmp.PixelFormat) \ 8
    Dim bmpData = bmp.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                                ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat)
    Dim bmpBuff((Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmpData.Height) - 1) As Byte

    Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, bmpBuff, 0, bmpBuff.Length)

    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData)

    Dim c As Color
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of Color, Point)

    For y = 0 To bmp.Height - 1
        For x = 0 To bmp.Width - 1
            i = y * bmpData.Stride + x * bpp
            c = Color.FromArgb(bmpBuff(i + 2), bmpBuff(i + 1), bmpBuff(i))

            ' Or color.ToArgb() = c.ToArgb() ...
            If colors.Any(Function(color) Color.op_Equality(color, c)) Then
                Dim p = New Point(x, y)

                If Not dict.ContainsKey(c) Then
                    dict.Add(c, p)
                ElseIf x > dict(c).X Then
                    dict(c) = p
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    If dict.Count > 0 Then
        Return dict.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Value.X).First().Key
    Else
        Return Color.Empty
    End If
End Function
```

Usage:

```vb
Sub Caller()
    Dim c As Color = GetLastColor(
        SomeBmp,
        Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0),
        Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0),
        Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 255))

    ' TODO: ...
End Sub
```

Here's a demo creates an image every two seconds and fills small rectangles with random colors at random positions. The last rectangle is the one with a circle.

[image: SOQ66656595]